A movie about Interstellar warfare
I am looking for this movie. I saw it in 2008. My memory is vague because I only watch a short scene of this movie.
Year : I saw it in 2008. My best guess it's released at least in 2005. 
Language: I don't know, really. When I saw it, there were no dialogue spoken. (probably Japanese/Korean, I'm not sure)
Style: 3D animated. Not a cartoon style (Disney, PIXAR etc). More likely an anime style (FF VII Advent Children, Saint Seiya: The Lost Canvas). The graphic is smooth and has nice effect.
Plot:
A male protagonist found an escape pod in a cave. While inspecting the pod, he is attacked by some kind of bomb. Then he got into his spacecraft and then there's a chasing scene between him and his attacker. The protagonist's spacecraft is small, maybe in the same size as alien spacecraft in Independece day). Eventually he is get hit with laser gun and his spacecraft is destroyed.  The chaser jumps from his spacecraft causing a mini shockwave. He is an axe wielding cyborg with a cape. Just as he want to swings his axe, an energy force is shot to his arm, damaging it. The caster is the female elf in the escape pod earlier. Then the screen zooming out, revealing a large scale of interstellar warfare. 
Update

I watched it at a anime and gaming festival in my country.


I'm not that familiar with it, but space battles, escape pods, cyborgs in capes and 3D animation all sounds like Clone Wars. Both the movie and the show are from 2008.

No it's not star wars animation. From the anime style I think it's japanese / korean.

Where did you see it?

Could it possibly be Battle for Terra?

@AidenGrossman no. It's not Battle of Terra. The animation style is different.

Have you searched anything in here https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/29/Space ? I you find something let me know so I can add as answer =)

This might be a silly question, but since you say you only saw a short scene and it was at a gaming festival, is there any possibility it was a game?

@Walt It could be. Maybe that's why I couldn't find it.

It's probably not any of these, but some popular anime that features galactic space are: Legend of the Galactic Heroes, Banner of Stars, Gundam/Macross, Outlaw Star, Space Battleship Yamato, Star Blazers, Captain Harlock.
